# How to create a box in viewport size width?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a box equal by my screen width,
my laptop screen viewport is 1360px * 625px,
but when I create a box in 1360px width,the browser show me a horizontal scrollbar.why?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Units</title>
        <style>
            *{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            .box{
                border: 3px solid red;
                width: 1360px;
                height: 625px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: `width: 100vw; box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Because `1360px + 3px + 3px > 1360px` … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 0):

Your browser window also takes up space. so unless you run your website full screen, it won't fit the browser screen and thus show you a scrollbar.

use width `100%` or `100vw` for setting the box to 100% width and set `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1360px width + 2 x 3px for border. So it's superior at your screen and add a scrollbar.